# Unable to filter and get just the return variable from a .ps1 script execution

Tags: windows, powershell, filter, return

```
$scriptPath = "${{ github.action_path }}\get_details.ps1"
$ServerName = "remoteserver777"

$returnArray = & "$scriptPath" -mypass ${{ inputs.mypass }} -myuser ${{ inputs.myuser }} -ServerName $ServerName

Write-Host "Print return data- $returnArray"
```

The .ps1 returns `cmdb_ci_linux_server,2,8.9,Test,10.130.68.70` which is what i want; but when i print `$returnArray` it has $ServerName `remoteserver777` that was passed as parameter to the .ps1 script.

Current output:

```
Print return data- remoteserver777 cmdb_ci_linux_server,2,8.9,Test,10.130.68.75
```

Desired Output:

```
Print return data- cmdb_ci_linux_server,2,8.9,Test,10.130.68.75
```

I then tried to only filter `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Output` and get the output returned by .ps1 script `return $returnValues` by trying the below:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command & 'D:\Git-Runners\s1_work_actions\newfeature\getdetails\get_details.ps1' -mypass *** -myuser svc_AMS_AppReliabilityEng -ServerName remoteserver777 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Output
Select-Object : Property "Output" cannot be found.
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Try ```write-host "Print return data- $($returnArray[-1])”```. Your current code is “stringifying” all the entries in the array - basically your ```write-host "print return data - $returnArray”``` is equivalent to ```write-host “print return data - $($returnArray -join “ “)”```, but you can just select the *last* item in the array with ```$returnArray[-1]```. See this tio.run - https://tio.run/##bYw7DsIwEET7PcXKQnQuOAAFDVIKToAonLAoFpYdrdeECHF244iPMGLKmTdvCCNx7Mk53QWmnE/Jd2KDx8Zfwpn0btqWBm6AJSNbIR2SDElQGWPUn7ptWwV3gEXs2A6Ca1SVS5WJSRL7DbOZyr7EFwvwVPUhFlENfX9mhTNRGn@k68@216tDpZlBtG/yc1M5PwA